# Getting user location not working?

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I am new to the MapView topic.Now I am working on the map view.I am getting the san Francisco location longitude and latitude values.I am testing in the simulator.It is not showing the current location longitude and latitude values.

With the help of this tutorial `http://www.creativeworkline.com/2014/12/core-location-manager-ios-8-fetching-location-background/` I am developing the app.

In AppDelegate file I wrote the following code like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

     UIAlertView * alert;

    //We have to make sure that the Background App Refresh is enable for the Location updates to work in the background.
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusDenied){

        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@""
                                          message:@"The app doesn't work without the Background App Refresh enabled. To turn it on, go to Settings > General > Background App Refresh"
                                         delegate:nil
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusRestricted){

        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@""
                                          message:@"The functions of this app are limited because the Background App Refresh is disable."
                                         delegate:nil
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    } else{

        self.locationTracker = [[LocationTracker alloc]init];
        [self.locationTracker startLocationTracking];

        //Send the best location to server every 60 seconds
        //You may adjust the time interval depends on the need of your app.
        NSTimeInterval time = 60.0;
        self.locationUpdateTimer =
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(updateLocation)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I have imported Location Tracker class in my ViewController

and I wrote the following code to get the location name and addresss

```
 CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    __block NSString *returnAddress = nil;

    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.appDelgate.locationTracker.myLastLocation_ completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

        if (placemark)
        {
            returnAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",placemark.subLocality,placemark.subAdministrativeArea];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithString:returnAddress] forKey:@"address"];

        }


    }];
```

Now my problem is that it is not going inside block.So that I am getting the "returnAddress" as (null).

I wrote like this even though it is not coming

```
- (void)updateLocationToServer {

    NSLog(@"updateLocationToServer");

    // Find the best location from the array based on accuracy
    NSMutableDictionary * myBestLocation = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for(int i=0;i<self.shareModel.myLocationArray.count;i++){
        NSMutableDictionary * currentLocation = [self.shareModel.myLocationArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if(i==0)
            myBestLocation = currentLocation;
        else{
            if([[currentLocation objectForKey:ACCURACY]floatValue]<=[[myBestLocation objectForKey:ACCURACY]floatValue]){
                myBestLocation = currentLocation;
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"My Best location:%@",myBestLocation);

    NSLog(@"latitude %@",[myBestLocation valueForKey:@"latitude"]);

      NSLog(@"longitude %@",[myBestLocation valueForKey:@"longitude"]);

    self.DICT=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:myBestLocation];

    //If the array is 0, get the last location
    //Sometimes due to network issue or unknown reason, you could not get the location during that  period, the best you can do is sending the last known location to the server
    if(self.shareModel.myLocationArray.count==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Unable to get location, use the last known location");

        self.myLocation=self.myLastLocation;
        self.myLocationAccuracy=self.myLastLocationAccuracy;

    }else{
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theBestLocation;
        theBestLocation.latitude =[[myBestLocation objectForKey:LATITUDE]floatValue];
        theBestLocation.longitude =[[myBestLocation objectForKey:LONGITUDE]floatValue];
        self.myLocation=theBestLocation;
        self.myLocationAccuracy =[[myBestLocation objectForKey:ACCURACY]floatValue];
    }

    NSLog(@"Send to Server: Latitude(%f) Longitude(%f) Accuracy(%f)",self.myLocation.latitude, self.myLocation.longitude,self.myLocationAccuracy);

       //TODO: Your code to send the self.myLocation and self.myLocationAccuracy to your server

    //After sending the location to the server successful, remember to clear the current array with the following code. It is to make sure that you clear up old location in the array and add the new locations from locationManager
    [self.shareModel.myLocationArray removeAllObjects];
    self.shareModel.myLocationArray = nil;
    self.shareModel.myLocationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    __block NSString *returnAddress = nil;
   self.locationActual = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[[myBestLocation objectForKey:LATITUDE]floatValue] longitude:[[myBestLocation objectForKey:LONGITUDE]floatValue]];

    //CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
   // __block NSString *returnAddress = nil;

    CLLocation *locloc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[myBestLocation objectForKey:LATITUDE]floatValue] longitude:[[myBestLocation objectForKey:LONGITUDE]floatValue]];

    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locloc completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

        if (placemark)
        {
            returnAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",placemark.subLocality,placemark.subAdministrativeArea];
            //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithString:returnAddress] forKey:@"address"];
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:returnAddress delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
        }


    }];


  }
```

What mistake i have done here.
Can anyone please help to clear this confusion.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you check what are you getting in myLastlocation_?

Comment: I have added a property @property (nonatomic) CLLocation *myLastLocation_;
in Location Tracker.h

Comment: How can i get the location information in my ViewController

Comment: Can you share the lat and long which is stored in mylastlocation?

Comment: latitude = "12.92243";
    longitude = "80.23893";

Comment: Are you sure you are using return address after completion? i have used the same above code and its working fine for me. I have updated my answer please check it.

Comment: @abhishekkharwar i edited the code can you please check it.
I added the code as you said.That alert is not coming

Comment: what are you getting in alert?

Comment: Iam not getting any alert>
AlertView popup is not coming.
Can u pls send me the example which u did?

Comment: That will be helpful for my app

Comment: hey did you check the source code?

Comment: You didn't use that classes right?Location Tracker.
I am fetching the user's location when app is running in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the return address after completion block? I have used the above code and its working fine.

Here you can download the [sample code](http://www.speedyshare.com/K5skh/Tute.zip)

```
 CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    __block NSString *returnAddress = nil;

    CLLocation *locloc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:12.92243 longitude:80.23893];

    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locloc completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

        if (placemark)
        {
            returnAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",placemark.subLocality,placemark.subAdministrativeArea];
            //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithString:returnAddress] forKey:@"address"];
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:returnAddress delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
        }


    }];


//If you try to access retunAddress here you will get nil.
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Can you share the lat and long values with us?

Comment: I edited my question now.Can you please check it and let me know what mistake i have done there.

Comment: I am try to get that return address in my MainViewController.Is it possible to get?

Answer (score 0):

Go to iOS Simulator -> Debug -> Location -> Custom location... And enter your long/lat coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

In the simulator there is no way to get the actual GPS based data so you need to simulate is with your lat-long which you can set by going

```
Debug -> Location -> Custom Location
```

and set your values there.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are simulating the location in the simulator. In your xCode's console panel there is an arrow button. Click that button and select "Don't simulate location". For reference, see the image.[image]

If that doesn't resolve the problem then run the application. Go into the Debug menu of the simulator and choose the "Custom location" option as shown in the image.
[image]